# How to query on firestore where field contains array of dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch project data from `FireStore` and here is my structure on firestore:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
FirestoreReferenceManager.rootProjects.whereField(
            FirebaseKeys.ProjectDetails.inviteData,
            arrayContains: [
                FirebaseKeys.ProjectDetails.otherUserId: userID,
                FirebaseKeys.ProjectDetails.inviteStatus: FirebaseKeys.ProjectDetails.pending
            ])
```

If I don't have `isInvoiceAccess` data on firestore then above code is working fine but when I add that key on firestore then above query is not giving me any results and I can not add that key because it can be `true` or `false`.

If I use below code then I am getting the results:

```
FirestoreReferenceManager.rootProjects.whereField(
            FirebaseKeys.ProjectDetails.inviteData,
            arrayContains: [
                FirebaseKeys.ProjectDetails.otherUserId: userID,
                FirebaseKeys.ProjectDetails.inviteStatus: FirebaseKeys.ProjectDetails.pending,
                FirebaseKeys.ProjectDetails.invoiceAccess: true
            ])
```

So I want data from `FireStore` without adding `isInvoiceAccess` in my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arrayContains` operation only checks whether there is exact match in the array, it cannot check for partial matches.

The common workaround for your use-case is to add an additional array field for each specific values/combination of values that you want to query on. So in your case, add a field `invites_uid_and_status` with just those two values for each, and then use *that* for this query.